# Tidying up a dataset in R

Tags: r

```
      patient  albumine  date       
  1       ID1  37       03.08.2019  
  2       ID1  39       07.06.2018 
  3       ID2  30       03.08.2019  
  4       ID3  45       07.06.2018  
  1       ID3  37       03.08.2019  
  2       ID3  39       07.06.2018  
  3       ID3  30       03.08.2019  
  4       ID3  45       07.06.2018
```

Dear all, This is my dataset and I would like to transform it into the following:

```
      patient  albumine1  date1    albumine2  date2        ...
  1       ID1  37       03.08.2019     39       07.06.2018  
  2       ID2
```

I tried

```
df2 <-df %>%
spread(key="patient", value="albumine")
```

Maybe someone has an idea?
**In the end, I would like to add an extra column to see whether a patient has had two or more albumin levels over 35 in the past two years.
Thank you very much for your help. This is my first question here, so I hope I provided enough data to help me.**

Best
Caro

Comment: Do you have an upper bound on how many times the `ID#` labels will be repeated in the original data frame? (In your example, `ID3` occurs 5 times and is the most frequent label.)

Comment: Dear Aaron, Thank you very much for your answer. My dataset includes 200 000 patients. But I managed to count that the ID that is most often repeated, is repeated 83 times. I appreciate your time and effort to help me.

Comment: Could you please provide your data using the `dput()` function? Providing the output of `dput(df)` makes it more easily reproduced by others. (And it could be a similar subset of the data that you show above.)

Comment: so in this case patient1 had 2 tests, patient2 one test and patient3 five test?

Comment: @CarolinV I would think your data is tidier as it stands now. You could get a result of patient ids of those with 2 or more albumin levels 35 or higher within the past 2 years without converting data to wide form. Would you be interested in that solution?

Comment: structure(list(X = 1:14, patient = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("ID1", "ID2", 
"ID3"), class = "factor"), albumine = c(35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 
40L, 34L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 33L, 46L, 22L, 48L), date = structure(1:14, .Label = c("11.11.19", 
"12.11.19", "13.11.19", "14.11.19", "15.11.19", "16.11.19", "17.11.19", 
"18.11.19", "19.11.19", "20.11.19", "21.11.19", "22.11.19", "23.11.19", 
"24.11.19"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-14L))

Comment: Dear Ben, Thank you for your answer in the long run, I want to identify cases and controls for a GWAS based on elevated/non-elevated albumin levels. If this is possible without reshaping the dataset. I would be delighted to know the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(splitstackshape)
dcast(getanID(df, 'patient'), patient~.id, value.var=c('albumine',"date"))
```

Answer (score 3):

Maybe something like this?

```
library(dplyr)
your.data.frame %>% 
  mutate(high.albumine = albumine>=35, 
         within.2.years = as.numeric(Sys.Date()-as.Date(date, tryFormats="%d.%m.%y"))<=365*2
         ) %>% 
  group_by(patient) %>% 
  mutate(high.albumine.within.2.years = sum(high.albumine&within.2.years)) %>%
  select(-high.albumine, -within.2.years)
```

Comment: This is a nice example with the addition of a column with number of albumin >= 35 tests within the past 2 years. It would be relatively easy to take this further to define which IDs could be cases vs. controls.

Comment: df<-df  %>%
  mutate(high.albumine = albumine>=35, 
         within.2.years = as.numeric(Sys.Date()-as.Date(date, tryFormats="%d.%m.%y")<=365*2
         ))
df2<-df%>% group_by(patient) %>%
           mutate(high.albumine.within.2.years = sum(high.albumine&within.2.years)) %>%
           select(-high.albumine, -within.2.years))

Comment: to me it works if splitted otherwise I get this error: Error in UseMethod("group_by_") : 
  no applicable method for 'group_by_' applied to an object of class "c('double', 'numeric')"

Comment: @PaoloLorenzini, I didn't filter the rows because the OP asked: _add an extra column to see whether a patient has had two or more albumin levels over 35 in the past two years_, so I wanted to preserve the information that was presented

Comment: I understand, nice. I guess it would be also good to add a line of code to filter out all those rows where the high.albumine&within.2.years is equal to zero or 1 in a way to get a list of patients ID who had two or more albumin levels over 35 in the past two years